# Adafruit Feather RFM69HCW Freezes During Use Requiring Hard Reset

Tags: c++, c, arduino, adafruit, radio-transmission

I'm helping build a prototype agriculturual machine. It's radio controlled using Adafruit radio modules:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-32u4-radio-with-rfm69hcw-module/overview

The system works OK, but the receiver intermitently freezes, requiring power off/on or a reset in order to come back to life. As the system is remote controlled this is unacceptable, and could potentially be dangerous given the nature of the machine.

Below is the code for the receiver. Basically a long list of 'if' statements with appropriate digitalWrite commands to turn various outputs off/on.

I'm fairly new to writing software like this, so I'm sure there's much that can be improved. However, the priority is working out why the module freezes from time to time.

Any help gratefully received! Thanks.

```
// INCLUDE PACKAGES
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF69.h>

// DEFINE RADIO FREQUENCY
#define RF69_FREQ 433.0

// DEFINE OUTPUTS
#define A_UP          13
#define A_DOWN        12
#define B_UP          11
#define B_DOWN        10
#define D_DOWN        18
#define E_UP          9
#define E_DOWN        6
#define F_UP          5
#define F_DOWN        19

#define C_1           20
#define C_2           21
#define C_3           22

// DEFINE RADIO PINS
#define RFM69_CS      8
#define RFM69_INT     7
#define RFM69_RST     4

// LOAD RADIO DRIVER
RH_RF69 rf69(RFM69_CS, RFM69_INT);

// CREATE GLOBAL VARIABLES
int16_t packetnum = 0;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(RFM69_RST, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RFM69_RST, LOW);

  Serial.println("Feather RFM69 RX Test!");
  Serial.println();

  // manual reset
  digitalWrite(RFM69_RST, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(RFM69_RST, LOW);
  delay(10);

  if (!rf69.init()) {
    Serial.println("RFM69 radio init failed");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("RFM69 radio init OK!");

  // Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, modulation GFSK_Rb250Fd250, +13dbM (for low power module)
  // No encryption
  if (!rf69.setFrequency(RF69_FREQ)) {
    Serial.println("setFrequency failed");
  }

  // If you are using a high power RF69 eg RFM69HW, you *must* set a Tx power with the
  // ishighpowermodule flag set like this:
  rf69.setTxPower(20, true);  // range from 14-20 for power, 2nd arg must be true for 69HCW

  // The encryption key has to be the same as the one in the server
  uint8_t key[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
                    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
  rf69.setEncryptionKey(key);

  pinMode(A_UP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A_DOWN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(B_UP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(B_DOWN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D_DOWN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(E_UP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(E_DOWN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(F_UP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(F_DOWN, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(C_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C_3, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(A_UP,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A_DOWN,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(B_UP,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(B_DOWN,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D_DOWN,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(E_UP,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(E_DOWN,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F_UP,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F_DOWN,HIGH);

  digitalWrite(C_1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C_2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C_3,HIGH);

  Serial.print("RFM69 radio @");  Serial.print((int)RF69_FREQ);  Serial.println(" MHz");
}


void loop() {

 if (rf69.available()) {
    // Should be a message for us now   
    uint8_t buf[RH_RF69_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
    if (rf69.recv(buf, &len)) {
      if (!len) return;
      buf[len] = 0;
      Serial.println((char*)buf);
      if (strstr((char *)buf, "A UP ON")) {
        digitalWrite(A_UP,LOW);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "A UP OFF")) {
        digitalWrite(A_UP,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "A DOWN ON")) {
        digitalWrite(A_DOWN,LOW);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "A DOWN OFF")) {
        digitalWrite(A_DOWN,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "B UP ON")) {
        digitalWrite(B_UP,LOW);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "B UP OFF")) {
        digitalWrite(B_UP,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "B DOWN ON")) {
        digitalWrite(B_DOWN,LOW);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "B DOWN OFF")) {
        digitalWrite(B_DOWN,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "D ON")) {
        digitalWrite(D_DOWN,LOW);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "D OFF")) {
        digitalWrite(D_DOWN,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "E UP ON")) {
        digitalWrite(E_DOWN,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(E_UP,LOW);
        delay(3000);
        digitalWrite(E_UP,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "E UP OFF")) {
        digitalWrite(E_UP,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "E DOWN ON")) {
        digitalWrite(E_UP,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(E_DOWN,LOW);
        delay(3000);
        digitalWrite(E_DOWN,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "E DOWN OFF")) {
        digitalWrite(E_DOWN,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "F UP ON")) {
        digitalWrite(F_UP,LOW);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "F UP OFF")) {
        digitalWrite(F_UP,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "F DOWN ON")) {
        digitalWrite(F_DOWN,LOW);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "F DOWN OFF")) {
        digitalWrite(F_DOWN,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "SPEED 0")) {
        digitalWrite(C_1,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(C_2,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(C_3,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "SPEED 1")) {
        digitalWrite(C_1,LOW);
        digitalWrite(C_2,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(C_3,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "SPEED 2")) {
        digitalWrite(C_1,LOW);
        digitalWrite(C_2,LOW);
        digitalWrite(C_3,HIGH);
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "SPEED 3")) {
        digitalWrite(C_1,LOW);
        digitalWrite(C_2,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(C_3,LOW
        );
      }else if (strstr((char *)buf, "SPEED 4")) {
        digitalWrite(C_1,LOW);
        digitalWrite(C_2,LOW);
        digitalWrite(C_3,LOW);
      }

    } else {
      Serial.println("Receive failed");
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATES:**

1. It appears that the program is well within the limits of the Adafruit board I'm using - the Arduino IDE reports this when I complile the program:

*Sketch uses 10612 bytes (37%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28672 bytes.
Global variables use 663 bytes of dynamic memory.*

2. I've declared *buf* as static:

*static uint8_t buf[RH_RF69_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];*

3. I've commented out all Serial.print() lines as they aren't required (there's no way of monitoring them within the device)

Comment: I'm suspicious of `buf[len] = 0;` in the loop; when `rf69.recv(buf, &len);` reads whatever it's reading, is it allowed to read *all the way* up to the full size of the buffer, such that `buf[len]` actually writes past the end of the array?  Might be better to add a byte of padding in the buffer definition, then remove one byte from the length offered to `recv()`

Comment: Also, how intermittent is it?  Every 5 minutes? Every 6 weeks?  Can you correlate the hangup with a particular command send to the device? I also just have to wonder if telling a device to `F UP` is asking for trouble :-)

Comment: @SteveFriedl thanks for the pointers - it's quite intermittent, but seems to happen when too many commands are sent. Running out of memory seems a likely cause as your query about the buffer seems to suggest, as Marcelo has also suggested in the answers?

Comment: Marcelo's answers are far more on point than mine, and look right on the money. But if I had this problem, I'd build a small test jig that the Feather sat in, perhaps connecting LEDs to the output pins, and then practice sending test commands at a high rate, watching for patterns of activity.  Even better would be a test jig that connected to a test computer, that could *read* the pins, then do end-to-end testing. Send command to Feather over radio, read pins back, log everything with timestamps. Find out what makes it break.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to enclose all your strings in F() macros, like F("blablabla"). Maybe you are running out of RAM, this is pretty common.
2. Check the linkage of your program and look for potential memory shortage:

> Sketch uses 3776 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253952 bytes.
>
> Global variables use 646 bytes (7%) of dynamic memory, leaving 7546 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes.

3. You have declared a buffer in the stack, I don't know the size of RH_RF69_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN, but that might be one of the causes of problem. Delcare it static uint8_t buf[RH_RF69_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];

Comment: Thanks so much for these pointers Marcelo. I've commented out all the serial print lines, as they're not required and have delcared 

static uint8_t buf[RH_RF69_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];

I'll send the code to my client to test and see if it's more reliable.